# Which dataset should I rely on to determine when a model is converged?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm confused about the plot of model accuracy during the training.
As you can see, the model seems converged in less than 10 epochs based on the validation set.
However, in terms of the training set, the accuracy is still changing until around 50 epoch.

So, to determine when a model is converged, which data set should we rely on?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by data set? Which graphic, or metric?

Comment: @Pake You see the legend at right lower corner, the orange line indicates validation while the blue line indicates the training set. The model is considered converged when the plot becomea a line.

Comment: thank you for helping me understand. Considering the definitions of training data and validation data, I think that the validation set is a good place for you to look. The validation set is giving you a look at how the model behaves on data it didn’t learn from, and you are probably most interested in how the model performs on data such as this.